# Get a key from array inside PHP Foreach statement

Tags: php, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I can't understand what's the problem with my code. I'am templating a website under Joomla! 2.5.9 and VirtueMart 2.0.20b.

I'am working on **Category page**`tplname/html/com_virtuemart/category/default.php` and **Product page**`tplname/html/com_virtuemart/productdetails/default.php`.

On the both pages i need to display a Tax in %: i.e.: 20% Tax.

For product page it's:

```
$product->prices['Tax'];
```

For category page it's:

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product):?>
    <li>
        <?php echo $product->prices['Tax'];?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Doing a `var_dump()` on both of these it gives me this output:

```
array
  204 => // <- Remember this number as FIRST ARRAY
    array
      0 => string 'TAXNAME_TITLE' (length=12)
      1 => string '10.0000' (length=7)  // <- I need this value!
      2 => string '+%' (length=2)
      3 => string '1' (length=1)
      4 => string '47' (length=2)
      5 => string '' (length=0)
      6 => string '1' (length=1)
      7 => string '204' (length=3)
```

To get a value I need, i do:

```
$productPriceTaxUnit = reset($product->prices['Tax']);
$productPriceTaxUnit = $productPriceTaxUnit['1'];
$productPriceTaxUnit = JText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_BASEPRICE_WITHTAX') . ' ' .number_format($productPriceTaxUnit, '2', '.', '') . '%';
echo $productPriceTaxUnit;
```

It works fine, but on a category page where `FIRST ARRAY` is equal to `204` gaves me an error, but if it's equal to `1` then everything is fine.

Someone see a wrong step i'am doing here ?

Thanks in advance

====== ** 1st UPDATED** ========

Here is a SQL debug:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS l.`virtuemart_product_id`
  FROM `ar9hu_virtuemart_products_sk_sk` as l JOIN `ar9hu_virtuemart_products` AS p using (`virtuemart_product_id`)
  LEFT JOIN `ar9hu_virtuemart_product_categories` as pc
  ON p.`virtuemart_product_id` = `pc`.`virtuemart_product_id`
  LEFT JOIN `ar9hu_virtuemart_categories_sk_sk` as c
  ON c.`virtuemart_category_id` = `pc`.`virtuemart_category_id`
  LEFT JOIN `ar9hu_virtuemart_product_shoppergroups`
  ON p.`virtuemart_product_id` = `ar9hu_virtuemart_product_shoppergroups`.`virtuemart_product_id`
  LEFT
  OUTER JOIN `ar9hu_virtuemart_shoppergroups` as s
  ON s.`virtuemart_shoppergroup_id` = `ar9hu_virtuemart_product_shoppergroups`.`virtuemart_shoppergroup_id`
  WHERE ( p.`published`="1"
  AND `pc`.`virtuemart_category_id` = 9
  AND `pc`.`virtuemart_category_id` > 0
  AND ( s.`virtuemart_shoppergroup_id`= "1" OR s.`virtuemart_shoppergroup_id` IS NULL ) )
  group by p.`virtuemart_product_id`
  ORDER BY `p`.product_sku ASC
  LIMIT 0, 10
```

====== ** 2nd UPDATED** ========

This is the error i am getting on category page:

```
    Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\wamp\www\baranik\templates\baranik\html\com_virtuemart\category\default.php on line 119
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0002  652096  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0714  9131016 JSite->dispatch( )  ..\index.php:42
3   0.0749  9542784 JComponentHelper::renderComponent( )    ..\application.php:197
4   0.0785  9691392 JComponentHelper::executeComponent( )   ..\helper.php:351
5   0.0789  9787480 require_once( 'D:\wamp\www\baranik\components\com_virtuemart\virtuemart.php' )  ..\helper.php:383
6   0.0980  12819808    JController->execute( ) ..\virtuemart.php:99
7   0.0980  12819888    VirtueMartControllerCategory->display( )    ..\controller.php:761
8   0.0980  12821880    JController->display( ) ..\category.php:60
9   0.1006  13209152    VirtuemartViewCategory->display( )  ..\controller.php:722
10  0.2021  19796592    JView->display( )   ..\view.html.php:244
11  0.2021  19796592    JView->loadTemplate( )  ..\view.php:205
12  0.2031  19910088    include( 'D:\wamp\www\baranik\templates\baranik\html\com_virtuemart\category\default.php' ) ..\view.php:649
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this had a downvote.  It seems like a valid question and the asker put valid research behind it.  +1

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Barmar - i've updated a question, please checkout 2nd Update

Comment: What's on line 119 of category/default.php?

Comment: @Barmar - `<?php echo $product->prices['Tax'];?>`, all i should did is make a test `if( isset($product->prices['Tax'];?>` and that's it...

Comment: The error message means that `$product` isn't an object. Your var_dump shows that `$products[204]` is an array, not an object, and the value you want is `$products[204][1]`. I don't know why it's different for `1` instead of `204`. How is `$products` filled in -- sometimes the element is an object, sometimes an array?

Comment: i don't understand that either, that was a dead end for me. but using `isset()` solve this

Comment: foreach ($products as $key=>$val)

Comment: @Bharanikumar - could you explain why using `$key` in `foreach` pls ?

Comment: to get keys from array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly but I can answer the title of your question.

'Get a key from array inside PHP Foreach statement'

You can iterate through the array and get the key and value using:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    echo "$key has a value of $value<br>";
}
```